# Spatial MSSQL ODBC error when using QGIS in 'Add Ring' operation

Tags: qgis-3, sql-server-spatial, odbc

I have a MSSQL spatial database using QGIS 3.28.4 as a front end.

I want to add a ring to a polygon and I get this message:

> Could not commit changes to layer HHP Developments
>
> Errors: ERROR: 1 geometries not changed.
> Provider errors:
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate
> "geometry":
> System.FormatException: 24142: Expected "(" at position 7729. The input has "C".
> System.FormatException:
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.RecognizeToken(Char
> token)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseLineStringText()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePolygonText()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseMultiPolygonText()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType
> type)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type,
> Int32 srid)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType
> type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid)
> . [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. QODBC3: Unable to execute statement

This error does not occur in QGIS 3.22.9; I have used this version of QGIS to successfully add the ring.

Is there a fix for this, perhaps in a newer version of QGIS?
Or do I need to post a bug report on GitHub?